How to Handle First Variation with Symbolic Computation in Mathematica?
Background
I am currently working on a problem related to surface tension and found a research paper that appears to have the information I need. I am attempting to replicate the calculations in this paper. Initially, I tried to solve their equations but encountered a numerical problem. I posted it on this website and have already received an answer from @AlexTrounev. Anyone interested in this topic can check it out.
Current Problem
Now, I am trying to use Mathematica to reproduce the first variation provided in this paper (Eq. 3.13). I defined the Gâteaux derivative, and the result actually looks good. Here is my code:
(*Define the lagrangian*)
Lg[x_, y_, \[Theta]_, \[Beta]_, r_, 
   DD_] := (EI/2)*Integrate[(D[\[Theta][s], s])^2, {s, 0, L}] + 
   w*\[Beta][s]*r[s]*\[Gamma] + 
   w*DD[s]*d\[Gamma] - \[Eta]*
    w*(Integrate[x'[s], {s, 0, DD[s]}] - 
      r[s]*Sin[\[Beta][s]]) - \[Mu]*
    w*(((r[s])^2/2)*(\[Beta][s] - (1/2)*Sin[2*\[Beta][s]]) + 
      Integrate[x'[s], {s, 0, DD[s]}]*
       Integrate[y'[s], {s, 0, DD[s]}] - 
      Integrate[y[s]*x'[s], {s, 0, DD[s]}]) + 
   Integrate[vi[s]*(x'[s] - Cos[\[Theta][s]]), {s, 0, DD[s]}] + 
   Integrate[ve[s]*(x'[s] - Cos[\[Theta][s]]), {s, DD[s], L}] + 
   Integrate[\[Lambda]i[s]*(y'[s] - Sin[\[Theta][s]]), {s, 0, 
     DD[s]}] + 
   Integrate[\[Lambda]e[s]*(y'[s] - Sin[\[Theta][s]]), {s, DD[s], L}];
(*Define the Gâteaux derivative*)
FullSimplify[
 D[Lg[x + \[Epsilon]*xt, 
    y + \[Epsilon]*
      yt, \[Theta] + \[Epsilon]*\[Theta]t, \[Beta] + \[Epsilon]*\
\[Beta]t, r + \[Epsilon]*rt, 
    DD + \[Epsilon]*DDt], \[Epsilon]] /. {\[Epsilon] -> 0}]

However, I found Mathematica can't handle the following integration automatically
\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(DD[s]\)]\(\*
SuperscriptBox["y", "\[Prime]",
MultilineFunction->None][s] \[DifferentialD]s\)\)

Thus, minor differences occur. I would like to know if there is any method to avoid this. Additionally, I am curious if there are any built-in functions to handle the first variation directly through operations on the Lagrangian. I don't know whether VariationalD can handle it or not since the boundary of each part is moving.

Your incriminated integral looks as
$$\int_0^{\text{DD}(s)} y'(s) , ds.$$
You have to separate local variables in sums, integrals, products, derivatives wrt to a symbol from global variables in boundaries and evaluated derivatives.

@Roland F Thanks for your advice. I am wondering why Integrate[f'[s],{s,0,DD}] can't be reduced to f(DD)-f(0) automatically. Moreover, since it is a variational problem, I don't know how to do operations correctly.

Its a feature of Mathematica not to apply any primitive rules to definite integrals. Somebody has deviated the evaluation to a bunch of methods including sophisticated methods from function analysis and complex analytic functions. The most primitive method to find and antiderivative and get the difference is not implemented. $$\int f'[x] dx = f[x]$$ but $$\int_0^1  f'[x] dx$$ does not evaluate. Perhaps one has to specify some conditions of continuity of $f$ at the end points, but I have given up.

@ Roland F Thank you for your explanation. I'd like to explore if there's a way to further reduce the expression to a simpler form, especially for such variational problem, otherwise the expression could be too complicated. I'd prefer a more straightforward representation if possible. If you have any suggestions or additional approaches that could help achieve this, I would be very grateful.
